# Bootstrap grid column size not applying to materialize styled dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, materialize

I have the following example I'm working through (only using materialize because of the multiselect drop down, so if there's an equally as visually pleasing alternative, I'm all for that):

```js
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('.multiselect').material_select();
            });
```

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
        <style>
          .input-field.col .dropdown-content [type="checkbox"]+label {
            top: -10px;
          }
        </style>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class='input-field col-3'>
              <select class='multiselect' multiple>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Datacenter</option>
                <option value="rs-iad">rs-iad</option>
                <option value="rs-lhr">rs-lhr</option>
                <option value="rs-ord">rs-ord</option>
                <option value="unknown">unknown</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

### [Demo Here!](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FNCBOSUEFXZG)

I'm trying to get the `col-3` working, but it just spans the entire page still. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your own code, you are using bootstrap 3.3:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >
```

There is no such thing as `col-3` in [bootstrap 3.3.x Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid).  In 3.3 you should be using `col-xs-3`.

You are also missing the actual bootstrap CSS file.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class='input-field col-xs-3'>
```

`col-3` only exists in Bootstrap 4 (beta as of this writing).

```js
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('.multiselect').material_select();
            });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
        <style>
          .input-field.col .dropdown-content [type="checkbox"]+label {
            top: -10px;
          }
        </style>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class='input-field col-xs-3'>
              <select class='multiselect' multiple>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Datacenter</option>
                <option value="rs-iad">rs-iad</option>
                <option value="rs-lhr">rs-lhr</option>
                <option value="rs-ord">rs-ord</option>
                <option value="unknown">unknown</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks - I've tried updating it to `col-xs-3` and it still doesn't work though.

Comment: Updated answer, you're missing bootstrap.css.

Comment: Oh, great - now if I can just get rid of that weird double caret.

Comment: Ah ok, looks like the _real_ answer here is for me to get rid of bootstrap altogether and use `class="col s3"` from materialize instead. Thanks!

Comment: No, nevermind that's not going to work -- the project I'm integrating into uses bootstrap, so yeah I'll need to figure out a way to get rid of the extra caret.